# How to implement a silent push notification in Flutter for Android and iOS?

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

Looks like FirebaseMessaging in Flutter handles background notifications on its own to display. Even when the 'notification' key is null it still shows an empty notification.

How to stop Flutter from displaying the notification when the app is in the background?

Here's the Python code that triggers the FCM notification (if you notice the `MulticastMessage` function only has `data` and no `notification`) -

```python
app = init_firebase()
androidNotification = messaging.AndroidNotification()
androidConfig = messaging.AndroidConfig(priority="high", notification=androidNotification,)

messageNotification = messaging.Notification(title=title, body=body)

apns = messaging.APNSConfig(
    payload=messaging.APNSPayload(aps=messaging.Aps()))

message = messaging.MulticastMessage(data=data,
                                     tokens=arr_tokens,
                                     android=androidConfig,
                                     apns=apns)

# send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
response = messaging.send_multicast(message, app=app)
```

Comment: "Even when the 'notification' key is null it still shows an empty notification." If the message has no `notification` property, the system should not handle its display. Can you show a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated the question, let me know if you need more information. 

Basically, this code triggers a notification that is supposed to land in the frontend without a notification actually being displayed, rather process something in the background in the app. 

However Firebase in Flutter seems to trigger a UI notification even if the 'notification' is Null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the field `notification` in `androidConfig` var, which is added to the message at the end of the function. Delete `notification=androidNotification` from `androidConfig` and it should work.